# Selecting first child label

Tags: html, css

Am I doing right selecting the first child label?

```css
.form-style-1 label:first-child{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-style-1 label{
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul class="form-style-1">
    <li>
      <label>Восстановление пароля</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Введите e-mail</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  /* More code*/
</form>
```

I would like to make only first label bolder but seems it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `label` is child of `li` so target to first li instead of targeting label:

```css
.form-style-1 li:first-child label{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-style-1 label{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul class="form-style-1">
    <li>
      <label>Восстановление пароля</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Введите e-mail</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`lable` is the child of `li` so that we have to use `first-child` or `nth-child(1)` on `li`. Write your css like below

```
.form-style-1 li:first-child label{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

or

```
.form-style-1 li:nth-child(1) label{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

then for normal text for 2nd label no need to write your second css.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-style-1 li:nth-child(1) label{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-style-1 label{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <ul class="form-style-1">
            <li>
                <label>Восстановление пароля</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Введите e-mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" />
            </li>
<form>
```

use like this